# How to force pip install of a package to eagerly update dependencies from the setup.py

Tags: pip, setuptools

### Problem to solve

How to force pip to install latest versions of dependencies from within the package's setup.py

#### Notes

This can't be solved by doing `pip install --upgrade-strategy eager` as the system doing that is not within our control. The reason this is a problem is because it's installing over a dirty environment (long story -- yes the right solution is use a clean environment, something we can't control or enforce in the current context unfortunately. It will eventually be done the correct way, but it won't be anytime soon).

Is there a way to specify in the setup.py that pip should update the dependencies eagerly?

### Workaround Solution

Manually pin things to versions, e.g. `"numpy>=1.18.1"`, that probably don't exist in the old dirty environment so pip has to install them

### Current setup.py for reference

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=[
        #...
        # Two examples of such packages to protect against using a dirty version
        # by forcing to a higher version
        'matplotlib>=3.2.1',
        'numpy>=1.18.1',
        #...
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Intended Audience :: Religion",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.7',
)
```